# Distributed cache Session returns NULL on seperate requests, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, session, .net-core, distributed-caching

please help!
the project is a .NetCore 3.1 MVC web application.
I am having an issue trying to make my Session to work with my distributed cache imprimentation.
Cache works well, its saved to the SQL server and retrieved well too.
then I tested the Session... If I Set on one request, and try to Get from another request, i ALWAYS get NULL, I've looked into all possible guides and cannot resolve the issue.
worth noting the session is being saved to my database, I just cannot access it!
this is my startup:

```
#define SQLServer // Redis





using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;



namespace DigitalBusiness.Caching.WebTester

{

    publicclassStartup

    {

        publicStartup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment hostEnviroment)

        {

            Configuration = configuration;

            HostEnviroment = hostEnviroment;

        }



        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public IWebHostEnvironment HostEnviroment { get; }



        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.

        publicvoid ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

        {

            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();



            if (HostEnviroment.IsDevelopment())

            {

                services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

                services.AddSession();

            }

            else

            {

#if SQLServer

                services.AddDistributedSqlServerCache(options => {

                    options.ConnectionString = Configuration["RawData"];

                    options.SchemaName = "dbo";

                    options.TableName = "SessionCache_Test_To_Remove";

                });

                services.AddSession(opts => {

                    opts.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);

                    opts.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;

                    opts.Cookie.IsEssential = true;

                });



#else

                services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options => {

                    options.Configuration = "localhost";

                    options.InstanceName = "SampleInstance"

                });

#endif

            }



        }



        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.

        publicvoid Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)

        {

            if (env.IsDevelopment())

            {

                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            }

            else

            {

                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");

            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();



            app.UseRouting();



            app.UseAuthorization();



            app.UseSession();



            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>

            {

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(

                    name: "default",

                    pattern: "{controller=CacheTester}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            });

        }

    }

}
```

and this is my controller methods.
Note: when i try to access the Session data i see the sessionCookie in the 1st call being returned to the client. but its not being added to consequent requests to the server... in addition, Expire is always -1.

```
        public void GetSession()

        {
//When i call this method, after i called the "SetSession" before, i get NULL

            var t = HttpContext.Session.GetString("123");

        }


        [HttpPost]

        public void SetSession([FromBody]model postData)

        {

            HttpContext.Session.SetString("123", "asd");

//Here i get the session value with no issues!

            var t = HttpContext.Session.GetString("123");


        }
```

Please save me :( Thank you in advance guys!

Answer (score 0):

Took me almost two days to find the issue which accrued in an unexpected place...
the damn client! i used MDN's fetch, but didn't add "Allow-Credentials: true", which means the the cookie was never saved by the browser...

a simple rookie mistake that ended up taking so much time...
I hope if u happen to get the same issue, you'll be able to solve it faster using my answer <3